# Como posso fazer um video player sem incluir o link do video?

Tags: html5

Imaginemos que eu quero criar um video player para o meu website. Eu usaria o seguinte código de html

```html
<video controls width="250">
    <source src="/media/videos/myvid.mp4"
            type="video/mp4">
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>
```

Mas eu não queria que uma pessoa que fosse examinar o código fonte pudesse obter o link para o vídeo facilmente. Qual seria a opção mais viável para esconder o link de fonte?
(Não tem obrigatoriamente que ser uma solução que só use HTML5 base, pode usar react, node ou até PHP, entre outros)

Comment: Cria uma página com o vídeo e embeda o vídeo por um iframe na página 'oficial', mesmo assim não sei se da certo, é só um teste para vc tentar

Comment: @hugocsl eu acho que isso funcionaria, mas a pessoa não poderia só aceder à página do iframe e por lá obter o link do video de qualquer jeito?